# Does Stack Overflow use LINQ to SQL generated classes directly?

Tags: discussion

Does Stack Overflow use the classes generated by [LINQ to SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_SQL)  directly in their application or how do they do it?

Comment: This was a close call, as this really is a programming question, but as it has to do specifically with SO as a website, it should be on Meta SO.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** we do, but we use less and less of this every day, in favor of [dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/).

Comment: meaning that, if you had the developer-time to do it, you would get rid of LINQ in favor of Dapper entirely? Thanks and +1